# Dry sauna using heat gun

Tags: heat

Thinking of building a small one person dry sauna and just running a heat gun blowing into bricks or rocks inside the sauna to heat it to 180F.

Any reason this would be dangerous?  Like the plastic cord releases toxic fumes at 160F and up or something silly like that?

Comment: There's no reason to think that it would be dangerous. There is reason to think that it'll be absurdly underpowered and die a quick death due to overuse, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fairly silly.  Of all the consumer electric products on earth, *heaters* are inherently the least expensive.  That is to say you can get cheap, good ones.

- A 1500-watt cheap tossie is $12 and will last a year.
- A quality oil-filled heater is $40 and will last 10-20 years.
- A proper, fixed-installation 2000W baseboard heater is $50 and will last 20-30 years.

So it's silly to misuse a tool for not its intended purpose, when the *right stuff* is easily affordable.

Even the wiring will be inexpensive, and I hope you'll do it right rather than hork something together with cheapie extension cords which are not rated for 1500W loads.  That's how the recent Oakland fire started.